# Bluetooth Headphones connects through bluetooth but is shown as disconnected in sound control panel

Tags: audio, drivers, bluetooth

About a month ago I bought an MBTOE70 Bluetooth headset and paired it to my computer that is using windows 10. but, I could not hear any sound.

The headphones appear to be connected through Bluetooth. However, it is shown as disabled in the Playback tab(the only tab that it should be shown I think) in the sound control panel. The obvious answer is to enable it and does not work.

This is the second time I got these specific headphones the first time worked fine for both my computer and android phone and now only works for my phone.

About the solutions, I have tried and did not work for me:

- Updating the drivers of Bluetooth headphones, headphones stereo, and the Microsoft Bluetooth Enumerator using Device Manager(also trying to uninstall them and add them back by adding the headset device again).
- Going to Devices and Printers and accessing the headset properties and checking all the boxes(Note: I don't have another Bluetooth device connected all I have is the computer speakers and the Bluetooth device as shown in the first image).
- Removing the com ports for the device and adding them back again.

[image]
[image]

**After 3 months no one had an answer to my question I am trying to revive this post if anyone has an answer, I will be very grateful!**

Update: after 6 months I asked this question, I started looking up over the headphones, and my guess since the driver for the sound of the headphones doesn't work on all PC's I've tried, then the headphones are just are broken when I purchased them. I will not recommend buying them since there are a few problems with them including a static sound when it is powered on and it is not soo comfortable to wear for my ears. Maybe even the audio isn't that great I'm not so sure.

Comment: "The headphones appear to be connected through Bluetooth." - Your screenshot indicates otherwise.  It specifically indicates your headphones are disconnected.

Comment: You are right il make it more clear by adding an image of the device connected through Bluetooth. The device did connect through Bluetooth the headset makes a sound when it is connected and states it. But, it does not connect in the sound control panel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a Year and 5 Months of digging information and failing to figure out the problem.

The way I have fixed the Bluetooth connection was through 3rd party Driver Updater by updating Bluetooth driver and serval windows updates of Windows 10 Home Edition (Each alone didn't satisfy this Weird cheap headset).

Hope this helps anyone who is struggling (A better way was to buy a better headset).